# Facebook SDK - Ant clean release failed

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ant

I just download latest facebook SDK from github. I import my facebook SDK into my cordova project, then when I try to build project using cordova build android, I'm always got this error in my terminal. I already done ant clean release, the error still remain. Currently using android sdk 19.

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 94 source files to /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Github/facebook-android-sdk/facebook/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Github/facebook-android-sdk/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java:349: warning: [deprecation] setSavePassword(boolean) in android.webkit.WebSettings has been deprecated
    [javac]         webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Github/facebook-android-sdk/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/PickerFragment.java:638: warning: [deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in android.view.View has been deprecated
    [javac]                 titleBar.setBackgroundDrawable(titleBarBackground);
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /Users/MNurdin/Documents/Github/facebook-android-sdk/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/PickerFragment.java:660: warning: [deprecation] setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) in android.view.View has been deprecated
    [javac]                     doneButton.setBackgroundDrawable(doneButtonBackground);
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] 3 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I already search the answers through stackoverflow but still can't get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. No need to use facebook SDK. I using this one instead facebook SDK from facebook.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect